# python calg library in windows x64

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, 64-bit

when i run python in windows 7 for x64,see this

[-]calg library: http://c-algorithms.sourceforge.net

[image]

why this and how do i can??

python calg library for  w3af in windows x64

any body don't konw?

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when trying to set up w3af on Mac (mavericks). It turned out that `pybloomfiltermmap` had not installed successfully with pip. I resolved it by manually downloading that from its repository - https://github.com/axiak/pybloomfiltermmap - and installing it according to the directions (python setup.py install).